# Javascript DOM Mouse Event is not working for IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, dom, file-upload

Working on the Custom File upload application. I have 2 major issues:

1. The following given below code is not Opening the File Dialogue Box for Mozilla and IE.
2. In Chrome its working, but when I select File on First Click, it never adds file to the body. But in second click it adds the file which was Browse in First Click to the body.

Any help for the above issues will be appreciated.

```
function perform1Click(node) {

            alert("INIT");
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
            node.dispatchEvent(evt);

            alert(3)
            getFile(evt);

        }

        function getFile(event) {

            var files = event.target.files;
            var totalSize = 0;

            if (totalSize > 1024*10) {

                alert('Total size exceed 1 Mb.');
                return;
            }
            //alert(files)
            //alert(files.length);
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                displayFileList(f.name, f.size);
                totalSize = totalSize+f.size;
            }
        }

        function displayFileList(name, size) {

            if (name != '') {

                var top_plugin = document.getElementById('top_plugin');

                // create tag 
                var ptag = document.createElement("p");

                // create div
                var divBox = document.createElement("div");
                divBox.setAttribute('class', 'divBox');

                // create input[type='checkbox']
                var inputCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
                inputCheckBox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                inputCheckBox.setAttribute('id', 'checkboxClass')

                // add checkbox to div.
                divBox.appendChild(inputCheckBox);

                // create text node for divBox and add it to divBox.
                var txtNode = document.createTextNode(name);
                divBox.appendChild(txtNode)

                var sizeDivBox = document.createElement("p");
                sizeDivBox.setAttribute('style', 'clear:both; display: inline-block;');

                var txtSizeNode = document.createTextNode(size);
                sizeDivBox.appendChild(txtSizeNode);
                divBox.appendChild(sizeDivBox);

                // add divBox to ptag.
                ptag.appendChild(divBox);
                //ptag.appendChild(divTxt);

                // add ptag to top_plugin div.
                top_plugin.appendChild(ptag);
            }

            // if file value is not null, make it blank.
            if (name != '')
            {
                name = '';
            }
        }
```

Comment: How you attach perform1Click to the event. Arg must be Event.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the same problems. Please find below the new code.

```
   function uploadDFiles() {

        var file = document.getElementById('_file');
        file.click();

        try {
            file.addEventListener("change", getFileName);
        }
        catch (e) {
            file.attachEvent("onclick", getFileNameOnIE);
            alert("Error:: "+e.description);
        }
    }

    function getFileName(event) {

        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            var fileName = f.name;
            var fileSize = f.size;

            var fSize = bytesToSize(fileSize, 2);

            displayFileList(fileName, fSize);
        }
    }
```

But now I have new problem. This code is not working in IE.For IE i am using attachEvent method and its not working. Please find below the code:

```
    function getFileNameOnIE(event) {

        alert(event.type);
        var files = event.target;
        alert(files.length);

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            displayFileList(f.name, f.size);
        }
    }
```

Can someone provide me the solution for the same now?

--

Tks
Bharat